# Google Spreadsheet - Time zones find text

Tags: timezone, find, google-sheets, utc

I have a Google Form where I ask people to tick their time zone and to tick their time slot. An anser may be (each answer is given in one cell):

Time Zone = UTC+8 (Perth, Beijing, Manial, Borneo, Singapore, Taipei)
   Time Slot = Morning (8am - 10am), Late Morning (10am - 12pm), Noon (12pm - 2pm), Afternoon (2pm - 4pm)

Now, I understand that having so much text instead of just a number, isn't helping any spreadsheet use, but somehow people get confused and this seems to be the only way I can get everyone to check the correct box. So in name of userfriendliness..

From these two cells I would like to calculate the time-slot into one particular time zone so I can compare them all(for example Amsterdam being UTC+1). I thought if I can use a function to lookup text, I can turn these cells into numbers.

IF cell CONTAINS "UTC+8" THEN = 8,

and doing the same for the time-slot, I can work with a modulo function or something and go ahead. But I just crossed over from Exel, and I must say Google Search isn't the same and I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with local dates and times, you either need to have an offset for each and every value, or you need to use the full time zone id (not just the offset) to know what those local times represent.  Simply doing math against the UTC offsets is not enough.  That won't take into account all of the different rules involved with time zones, such as daylight savings / summer time.

I am not very fluent with Google Spreadsheet - but it does appear that they have some functions for time zone conversion built in.  I am not sure how accurate they are, but you should review [this blog post](http://victorwyee.com/gapps/change-time-zone-date-time-data-google-spreadsheets/), which has some good information.